# Why is the function "Simplex" not working?

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve this PL with R Studio:

```
a<-c(3,4)
A<-matrix(c(2,3,2,1,1,3),nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
b<-c(180, 120, 150)
result<-simplex(a, A1=A, b1=b, maxi=TRUE)
```

I got this after running the last line

> Error in simplex(a, A1 = A, b1 = b, maxi = TRUE) :
> could not find function "simplex"

how can i solve it ?

Comment: There’s no function called `simplex` in R. You will need to load a package (e.g. ‘boot’) that defines this function (or write it yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the function simplex you need to import it first. Simplex is part of the boot-package, you can install and activate it with (usually written at top of the script):

```
install.packages("boot")
library("boot")
```

Now it should work.